# error CS0120: An object reference is required to access non-static member

Tags: c#, static, unity-game-engine

Fairly new to Unity and I've been getting through my game with not too many hiccups but I'm stumped on this one.
The error I'm getting is:

> Assets/Scripts/Interactables/ButtonMoveObject.cs(25,55): error CS0120: An object reference is required to access non-static member `Inventory.CheckItem(Inventory.items)'

I can't seem to figure it out, any thoughts?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ButtonMoveObject : MonoBehaviour {

//Object name to link to button
public GameObject buttonReceiver = null;

//Target for moved objects and time it takes
private Vector3 source;
public Vector3 target;
public float overTime;

//Prerequesites required to operate it
public Inventory.items[] pres;

//Flag to keep checking prerequisites and check count
private bool checkFlag = true;
private int checkCount = 0;

void Use ()
{
    if (pres.Length > 0) {
        while (checkFlag) {
            checkFlag = Inventory.CheckItem(pres[checkCount]);
            if (checkCount == pres.Length) {
                if (checkFlag) {
                    checkFlag = false;
                    StartCoroutine (MoveObject ());
                }
            }
            checkCount++;
        }
    }
}

IEnumerator MoveObject()
{
    source = buttonReceiver.transform.position;
    float startTime = Time.time;
    while(Time.time < startTime + overTime)
    {
        buttonReceiver.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(source, target, (Time.time - startTime)/overTime);
        yield return null;
    }
    buttonReceiver.transform.position = target;
}

}
```

EDIT:

Okay I've fixed it with `checkFlag = player.GetComponent<Inventory>().CheckItem(pres[checkCount]);`
but now I'm getting an error `Assets/Scripts/Player/Inventory.cs(21,30): error CS0176: Static member Inventory.items.keycardGreen' cannot be accessed with an instance reference, qualify it with a type name instead`

in my Inventory script

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Inventory : MonoBehaviour {

public enum items
{
    keycardGreen,
    keycardRed
};

//Inventory List
[HideInInspector]
public bool keycardGreen = false;
[HideInInspector]
public bool keycardRed = false;

public void CollectItem (items newItem)
{
    switch (newItem) {
    case newItem.keycardGreen:
        keycardGreen = true;
        Debug.Log(newItem + " collected.");
        break;
    case newItem.keycardRed:
        keycardRed = true;
        Debug.Log(newItem + " collected.");
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

public bool CheckItem (items checkItem)
{
    switch (checkItem) {
    case checkItem.keycardGreen:
        return keycardGreen;
        break;
    case checkItem.keycardRed:
        return keycardRed;
        break;
    default:
        Debug.Log("Item does not exist.");
        break;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `CheckItem()` in the `Inventory` class is not static. You need an `Inventory` instance to call it on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either need an instance of class Inventory:

```
Inventory inv = new Inventory();
while (checkFlag) {
    checkFlag = inv.CheckItem(pres[checkCount]);
    if (checkCount == pres.Length) {
        if (checkFlag) {
            checkFlag = false;
            StartCoroutine (MoveObject ());
        }
    }
    checkCount++;
}
```

or the CheckItem-method to be static:

```
static bool CheckItem(Inventory.items item) {... }
```

Comment: Okay I get it, I've fixed it but now I'm now I'm getting other errors. I've edited my main post.